# Does Chrome violates the HTML5 standard for Geolocation API when position is unavailable?

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, w3c-geolocation

While I am developing a web app, I am using HTML5 Geolocation API. I have done the following steps:

1. I turned off my WiFi connection on my desktop computer.
2. I triggered a position request using :

   ```
   var params = {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout:3600, maximumAge:60000};
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( reportPosition, gpsError, params );
   ```
3. I run my HTML code using Google Chrome Browser [version 41.0.2272.89 (64-bit)] and I found out that `gpsError` function has been called twice. In the first time I got an error code `POSITION_UNAVAILABLE` which makes sense to me since the connection was off. But surprisingly, I found out that the error code in the second time is `TIMEOUT`.
4. I run the same code on Safari [version 8.0.4 (10600.4.10.7)] and the `gpsError` function was called only once with error code `POSITION_UNAVAILABLE`
5. I opened the geolocation [standard](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#geolocation_interface) and I found out the following steps:

   [image]

But in section [5.2 PositionOption interface](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#position_options_interface) , it states the following:
[image]

So I guess chrome violates the standard of Geolocation API because it does not make sense to me to invoke error callback with `TIMEOUT` after knowing the fact that postion is not available i.e. invoking error callback with `POSITION_UNAVAILABLE`

Which one is considered to be compliant with the standard, the chrome or safari?